# .whl file can't be downloaded from the pypi website

Tags: matplotlib

When trying to download matplotlib-3.0.2-cp37-cp37m-win32.whl on the website of pypi, I got the choice to open or to save it (not to download it). After opening and saving I got the message: .whl-file can't be opened because this file type will not be supported. After I clicked ok, suddenly the acrobat reader opened. I also tried the website www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke. 
How can I download the .whl-file?

Comment: As usual, in your browser you should be able to right-click the link and choose "Save linked file as..." or similar.

Comment: It seems you have downloaded it successfully. You should not open it using any text editor. You should just use `pip install xxx.whl`, so the package can be installed.

Comment: I tried to right-click the link, I'll get a pop up screen with the name and type of file. Type of file stands on adobe acrobat reader. I can't change it.